gdstk Boolean too slow but works fast in Klayout?
I am trying to cut out several holes in a rectangle. When I do this in Klayout using "Subtract others from first", the result is computed almost instantly. However, when I try to do it using gdstk, it is very slow! Am i doing something wrong?
The Klayout GUI boolean operation works very fast somehow as I am selecting all the polygons to be cut at once with multiple selection. I suspect this is different from the sequential for loop update for each cut operation im doing using gdstk. Is there a smarter + faster way to do this in gdstk? Many thanks for your help!
import gdstk

# parameters for the design

dc =5.8
eps = 1/20
cW=2000
d = 70
cL = 10000
g = dc/(1.4*(eps)**0.48) 

# create gds library and cells

lib = gdstk.Library()
pD = lib.new_cell("post")
pRow = lib.new_cell("pArray")
pRef = lib.new_cell("pRef")
clip = lib.new_cell("clip")
inv = lib.new_cell("invDld")

# construct geometries 

pD.add(gdstk.ellipse((0,0), d/2, tolerance=0.01))   # unit cell for array
box = gdstk.rectangle((-cL/2,-cW/2),(cL/2,cW/2))    # box to cut from

ny = int(cL / (g + d)) + 1                  # ncols
nx = int(cW / (g + d)) + 1                #  nrows
spc = d + g                                      # array spacing
extras = int(ny*eps) + 1

# create array 

for i in range(ny):
    arr = gdstk.Reference(pD, origin = (i*spc,i*eps*spc - extras*spc), columns = 1, rows= nx + extras, spacing = (0,spc))
    pRow.add(arr) 
rowRef = gdstk.Reference(pRow, origin = (-cL/2,-cW/2), columns = 1, rows= 1, spacing = (0,0))
pRef.add(rowRef)

 # mask to trim off edges

mask = gdstk.boolean(gdstk.offset(box, (extras+2)*spc)[0], box, 'not')[0]

# remove posts that fall outside box

pols = pRef.flatten().polygons
for i in range(len(pols)):                                 <<<<  This is also relatively slow
    res = gdstk.boolean(pols[i], mask, 'not')               
    if res != []:
        if res[0].area() > 25:
            clip.add(res[0])
clip.add(box)                                                             # cell containing mask and objects to cut

lib.remove(pRef, pRow, pD)                                              # remove unwanted cells

# flatten structures to perform boolean cut

clipFlat = clip.flatten()
pols = clipFlat.polygons

# perform inversion! This is where it fails <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

res = gdstk.boolean(box,pols, "not")[0]
inv.add(res)

lib.write_gds("minimalExample.gds")

I have also tried simply using
res = gdstk.boolean(box,pols, "not")[0]
as you see in the minimal example above and this returns an empty list, which is not the correct output.

Removing the line clip.add(box) solves the problem. However, the earlier section of the code where the pRef polgons are cut from the mask, still needs to be perfomed in a for loop. I can't get it to run without this...
 import gdstk

# parameters for the design

dc =5.8
eps = 1/20
cW=2000
d = 70
cL = 10000
g = dc/(1.4*(eps)**0.48) 

# create gds library and cells

lib = gdstk.Library()
pD = lib.new_cell("post")
pRow = lib.new_cell("pArray")
pRef = lib.new_cell("pRef")
clip = lib.new_cell("clip")
inv = lib.new_cell("invDld")

# construct geometries 

pD.add(gdstk.ellipse((0,0), d/2, tolerance=0.01))   # unit cell for array
box = gdstk.rectangle((-cL/2,-cW/2),(cL/2,cW/2))    # box to cut from

ny = int(cL / (g + d)) + 1                  # ncols
nx = int(cW / (g + d)) + 1                #  nrows
spc = d + g                                      # array spacing
extras = int(ny*eps) + 1

# create array 

for i in range(ny):
    arr = gdstk.Reference(pD, origin = (i*spc,i*eps*spc - extras*spc), columns = 1, rows= nx + extras, spacing = (0,spc))
    pRow.add(arr) 
rowRef = gdstk.Reference(pRow, origin = (-cL/2,-cW/2), columns = 1, rows= 1, spacing = (0,0))
pRef.add(rowRef)

 # mask to trim off edges

mask = gdstk.boolean(gdstk.offset(box, (extras+2)*spc)[0], box, 'not')[0]

# remove posts that fall outside box

pols = pRef.flatten().polygons
for i in range(len(pols)):                                 <<<<  This is also relatively slow
    res = gdstk.boolean(pols[i], mask, 'not')               
    if res != []:
        if res[0].area() > 25:
            clip.add(res[0])

lib.remove(pRef, pRow, pD)                                              # remove unwanted cells

# flatten structures to perform boolean cut

clipFlat = clip.flatten()
pols = clipFlat.polygons

# perform inversion! This is where it fails <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

res = gdstk.boolean(box,pols, "not")[0]
inv.add(res)

lib.write_gds("minimalExample.gds")

